# How to get python to use the datetime into making a calender

Tags: python, datetime, calendar

I want to print out a calendar that automatically shows the current month and year without the user or coder doing anything to the code so that python gets the current month and year. can anyone help i don't mind if you completely change the code im a beginner so need so me help.

```
import time
import datetime



a = ("Current year: ", datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y"))
b = ("Month of year: ", datetime.date.today().strftime("%B"))

import calendar

yy = int(a)
mm = int(b)

# display the calendar
print(calendar.month(yy, mm))
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code up to `import calendar`. Just `print(a)` and `print(b)`. You've made them into tuples of text, then try to convert them to integers, which is impossible. If you need `b` as an integer, use `b = int(datetime.date.today().strftime("%m"))` - you're converting to the string name of the month currently.

Comment: can you just show us what you want as the output? The part i dont understand is you are creating tuples a, b and trying to convert to int... which is not possible. Also if you want month as  a string you use "%B" & if you want month as an integer use "%m"

Comment: Notice that the value of `a` will be `("current year:", "2019")` and using the `int` function on that will give you a TypeError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with your code was that you had Month saved as "January" instead of `1` (`"%M"` instead of `"%B"` in `strftime()`). Also there's no point to store `a` and `b` as tuples, all we need is second value of that tuple.

```
import time
import datetime

a = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y") # '2019'
#b = datetime.date.today().strftime("%B")  'January'
b = datetime.date.today().strftime("%M") # '00'

import calendar

yy = int(a)     # 2019
mm = int(b) + 1 # 0 + 1

# display the calendar
print(calendar.month(yy, mm))
```

**Output**

```
    January 2019
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
    1  2  3  4  5  6
 7  8  9 10 11 12 13
14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27
28 29 30 31
```

Comment: Hello , you could use "%m" instead of "%M" and then adding 1

Comment: Glad to have been of help! You can accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you. :)